# How can I use external libraries with the scripts atom package and java?

Tags: java, atom-editor

How do I go about configuring the classpath when using the scripts package with atom/java?

I know my classpath is:

usr/local/algs4/algs4.jar

Here is the code I am testing with:

import edu.princeton.cs.algs4.*;

public class Wget {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    // read in data from URL
    String url = args[0];
    In in = new In(url);
    String data = in.readAll();

    // write data to a file
    String filename = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
    Out out = new Out(filename);
    out.println(data);
    out.close();
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using algs4, Use Princeton's site and search for classpath.
http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/code/

Comment: I know what the class path is but I am trying to figure out where to add it in my "Script" (the atom package) configuration